# Limit of $\sum_{t=0}^n a_n(t)$ for n tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, probability-theory

I am wondering about how to deal with a limit of the following form
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{t=0}^n a_n(t),$$
with the function $a_n(t)$ and the sum being dependent on $n$.
Consider the example
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{t=0}^n \Big(1-\frac{t}{n}\Big)^n.$$
The sequence $\Big(1-\frac{i}{n}\Big)^n$ converges obviously for $n \rightarrow \infty$.
However, I feel
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{t=0}^n e^{-t}=\frac{1}{1-e}$$ may in this case not be a correct usage of the limit.

Originally, this question is motivated by the computation of a ratio distribution
$$ \mathbb{P}\Big[ \frac{X}{Y} = z \Big]= \sum_{t=0}^n t \cdot \mathbb{P}[ X=tz, Y = t ]$$
of two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$. I considered first the joint $\mathbb{P}[ X=tz, Y = t ]$ independently and let terms involving $n$ converge. Then, once I saw the $n$ in the outer sum, I realized this was maybe not the best idea.

Comment: Look up Tannery's theorem.

Comment: Thumbs up, exactly what I was looking for. Thx!